# preg_match wrong result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Pretty self explanatory: what's going on? Why do this string (the 2 casted) return a match but empty? Instead of a just empty array?

```
php > preg_match("/[a-z\s\']*/", (string)2, $matches);
php > var_dump($matches);
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}
php >
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using the `*`, which indicates the regex should match 0 or more occurrences of the character class. It matches the zero occurrences in the string, and reads them into the match array.

Answer (score 1):

`*` matches zero or more of the preceding token. As that's all you're looking for, a zero-length string matches. If you want no matches, replace `*` with `+` to require at least one of the preceding token.